# How to update inner document in node using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to insert cont and cont_type inside pro_picture. But this is not a embedded schema.

My schema:

```
 var userSch = new Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    profile_picture: {
       cont: String,
       cont_type: String
    }
 });

 var User = mongoose.model('user', userSch);
```

Now I want to find the user whose email is "something@example.com' and update the pro_picture.

I tried the following code.

```
  User.findOne({email: data.email}, function (err, user) {
   var userData = new User({
      profile_picture: {
        cont: data.pro_cont,
        cont_type: data.pro_cont_type
      }
    });
   user.profile_picture = userData;
   console.log(user.profile_picture);
   console.log(user);


  user.save(function (err) {
    if(err) throw err;
    callback(rjTypes.result.SUCCESS);
  });
```

It shows

```
profile_picture: null  //in console
```

but the field is not present in collection

Comment: try to log the user and data variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found it..

I solved by using this technique....

```
User.findOne({email: data.email}, function (err, user) {
    user.profile_picture.cont = data.pro_cont;
    user.profile_picture.cont_type = data.pro_cont_type;
    console.log(user.profile_picture);
    console.log(user);
    //user.profile_picture.cont_type = data.pro_cont_type;
    user.save(function (err) {
      if(err) throw err;
      callback(rjTypes.result.SUCCESS);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're doing one nesting to much, try changing

```
var userData = new User({
   profile_picture: {
     cont: data.pro_cont,
     cont_type: data.pro_cont_type
   }
 });
```

to

```
var userData = {
     cont: data.pro_cont,
     cont_type: data.pro_cont_type
};
```